# is it a good idea to use CICS transaction gateway in open source?

Tags: websphere, open-source, mainframe, zos, cics

for know the CICS transaction gateway is used in Z/OS but we want to move it to either redhat8 or windows server 2019 and i want to know if any one had done this before in order to ask him if it was a good idea did it work with no problem? or was it a mistake to do that ?

Thank you so much in advance

we expect that the Ctg will work with no problem in windows server or redhat

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: This is an unanswerable question, as is.  CICS Transaction Server runs on z/OS or z/VSE; there is no way I know of to run it on RedHat or Windows server.  There's CICS Transaction Gateway that can run on a variety of platforms.  There are various CICS clients available that run on a variety of platforms.  What's appropriate for your situation no one can say unless you give a lot more details.

Comment: first thank you so much for your answer, actually as you said my question wasn't clear , I'm talking about CICS transaction gateway, the CTG 9.3 to be more specific, we want to run it either on REDHAT8 or windows server 2019 , knowing that for now it actually run on Zos, i want to know if someone already did this operation in order to see if it was a success? if they faced any problem doing it? does it work well? in other words i need a return of experience or just an opinion about this operation, it would be so great if you could help me even an information or just an opinion would help

Comment: CTG 9.3 runs on Redhat and windows too. It is successful and works well.
https://www.ibm.com/common/ssi/ShowDoc.wss?docURL=/common/ssi/rep_ca/8/897/ENUS222-068/index.html
this link gives you the flavors where CTG can run

Answer (score 1):

CICS Transaction Gateway for Multiplatforms v9.3 is supported on both Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 and 8 and Windows 2019 and 2016.  See https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cics-tg-multi/9.3?topic=components-operating-systems for more information on compatible software products.

There are a number of CICS customers who are using CICS TG on Linux and Windows to connect to their CICS regions running on z/OS.

Comment: thank you a lot Mr.Compton for your time and your answer.